# Autofac ASP.NET Core 2.0 Property Injection failing

Tags: autofac, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a base class that I want to inject the properties in it.
I have tries to configure the base class with PropertiesAutowired, also I have tried OnActivated resovling the property.  Both seem to fail.

Any ideas.

Regards

Comment: Need a lot more info [like a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was missing ".AddControllersAsServices();" from services.AddMvc();